# Rails app - send_data sending garbled documents from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, ms-access, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using a rails app to display data that is stored in a sql server db.  Data entry is all done through an MS Access front end into the sql server db.   The rails app is "read only" viewer of information entered via the access app.

In the access front end, I use a bound object frame to let users upload documents of various types (.pdf, .msg, .docx etc.) into the database. The object is stored in a varbinary field on my sqlserver.   This works fine when using the Access front end. Docs  are properly retrieved and displayed with the right host app.

The problem is when sending those same objects back to be viewed through the rails app.

When I try to send the  binary data down through the browser the file as a file, the file received is unreadable by its host app. The file extension is correct for the file sent down, but the applicaiton cant' seem to read them.  I'm definitely getting something coming down -- when I examine the files in notepad I see snippets of the text, but something is wrong with the files so they are unreadable by MS Word  or PDF Reader, etc.

The code in the controller is pretty simple:

```
def view_word_doc

  a=Attachment.find(params[:id])
  send_data a.Document, :filename => 'flibber.docx'
 end
```

(Document is the field int he table that has the varbinary)

This has the expected result in the browser, I am asked if I want to open or save the file, and it attempts use word to open the doc.  However word says the document is corrupted.  Similar results when I try to open .pdf, .msg files etc.

I also tried using send_file.  In that case I get a controller error --

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in AttachmentsController#view

"\x81" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8

I have left the type to default, which I understand is Application/Octet-stream but I'm not so familair with what this means.

As I mentioned, this all works fine with the access front end.  Just can't send it properly in rails.

Comment: `Application/Octet-stream` basically forces the browser to download the data as a file, not display it in the browser.  For example, using `Application/Octet-stream` for PDF will make it so the PDF does not come up in a browser window.  Regarding your problem, I would GUESS that it is an encoding issue.  Have you played around with the encoding?

Comment: To elaborate more, it looks like your system is not handling something right with the conversion from rails data (UTF-8) to the data that MS Access is using (Windows-1252) to enter the data.

Comment: So it seems like the files are intact in the db since access app can read them, but when sendfiles sends them I cant figure out how to get the file to send is "Windows-1252" whatever that is.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `send_file path, :type => 'application/msword',`? Octet stream may not be what you want since msword docs will download automatically.  Taking a stab here.

Comment: Yep, when I do that I get "Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in AttachmentsController#view

"\x8F" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8" again

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have coded to receive the files as a `GET` method in your routes.rb so it attempts to display them inline/in the browser or potentially a link used in the view whereas it needs to be a button which uses the **`POST`** method by default.